# Is there any tool for data visualization and manipulation?

Tags: visualization, supervised-learning, preprocessing, labels

I have a time series data set that I need to manually label for supervised learning.

What I am doing now is using excel to the plot, and when I see the pattern that I want, I hover over the data on the plot, read its index, then mark the data accordingly on the data. I think it is not very efficient, for example, I can not zoom or scroll.

I want to ask is there any tool that I can visualize the data, and manipulate the data at the same time, please.

Comment: All dashboard software that I know do not allow to manipulate data. But you can program a javascript webpage that will use some javascript library to show the data and you add some javascript code to manipulate the data. For example, on click event.

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion, but I am not very familiar with Javascript. Do you have any other advice?

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using? A quick Google search of {lang} visualization can help you with this.

For example, Python has Bokeh, Pandas, and Seaborn. Bokeh is for interactive visualizations which can help with digging deeper into the visualizations. See:

[Are there any python based data visualization toolkit?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/235/are-there-any-python-based-data-visualization-toolkit?rq=1)

Comment: but isnt it only for visualization? i m looking for a way that i can interact with my data visually, not just view, but also manipulate. for example, i plot the data out, zoom/scroll whatever to visually analyse it, when i see the pattern that i am interested, i can select the data point or the range, right click and label it

Comment: You can do that too..

https://towardsdatascience.com/data-visualization-with-bokeh-in-python-part-one-getting-started-a11655a467d4

Comment: i will take a look, many thanks! I always think it is just a interactive visualization tool, not able to manipulate the data

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tableau Public Software. Tableau Public version is a freeware in which you can connect to basic data sources such as excel, csv etc.

The visualizations in Tableau can be made easily -you can also interact with the graphs in various ways (like zoom in zoom out) and it doesn't require high-level coding skills.

Download it from there official website: https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/

You can also learn some Tableau basics from here: https://www.tableau.com/learn/training

Comment: can i also manipulate the data and it shows the live result?

Comment: What I understood form manipulation is that you want to draw out results from the visualisation. That you can do but it won't be a live kind of thing. You can create your calculated fields which derives the conclusions from the view. Then you will have to download the data again from tableau, which will contain those new columns that you have created. On the other side, by manipulation you mean write back to the data using tableau, that we can't achieve directly.But, Like Keiv.fly suggested, we will have to use java script for it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's what you need, but for data mining without a single line of code (it works with widgets that you drag and drop), **[orange](https://orange.biolab.si/)** is definitely the way to go.